# index-small-if with multiple criterias from the same column

Tags: excel, indexing

I have following index-small-if array formula which works great if I have one criteria=SalesOrderId.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table_michael_pc_inflowsql_inFlow_SO_SalesOrder_Line,SMALL(IF(Table_michael_pc_inflowsql_inFlow_SO_SalesOrder_Line[SalesOrderId]=SalesOrderId,ROW(Table_michael_pc_inflowsql_inFlow_SO_SalesOrder_Line[SalesOrderId])-1),ROWS(A$28:A28)),13),"")
```

Now if I have a second criteria called "SalesOrderId2" which looks up same data as first criteria I cannot make it work to show the result from both criterias from cell A28 up.

Comment: Have you considered adding a helper column that combines SalesOrderId and SalesOrderId2 into one, then just looking up that though a standard `VLOOKUP`?  The reason I suggest this is that, while useful, array function can be quite expensive because it would look through all values twice to find a single result.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you right. Could you give me an example?

Comment: [Here is an illustrated step-by-step guide](http://exceltactics.com/faster-multiple-criteria-lookups-vlookup-concatenate/) that should help explain what I mean, if this doesn't fit your need we can try something else.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work as the range for criteri1 and criteria2 is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state that you have a working formula but to my eye there is either a problem with the existing formula or it is designed for a very specific purpose. In any event, I will take your word for it that is what you want.

You have not disclosed whether this added criteria should be of the `AND` or `OR` variety so here are both as well as an alternate.

For *table*[SalesOrderId]=SalesOrderId **AND** *table*[SalesOrderId2]=SalesOrderId,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table_michael_pc_inflowsql_inFlow_SO_SalesOrder_Line, SMALL(IF(Table_michael_pc_inflowsql_inFlow_SO_SalesOrder_Line[SalesOrderId]=SalesOrderId, IF(Table_michael_pc_inflowsql_inFlow_SO_SalesOrder_Line[SalesOrderId2]=SalesOrderId, ROW(Table_michael_pc_inflowsql_inFlow_SO_SalesOrder_Line[SalesOrderId])-1)), ROWS(A$28:A28)), 13),"")
```

For *table*[SalesOrderId]=SalesOrderId **OR** *table*[SalesOrderId2]=SalesOrderId,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table_michael_pc_inflowsql_inFlow_SO_SalesOrder_Line, SMALL(IF(Table_michael_pc_inflowsql_inFlow_SO_SalesOrder_Line[SalesOrderId]=SalesOrderId, ROW(Table_michael_pc_inflowsql_inFlow_SO_SalesOrder_Line[SalesOrderId])-1, IF(Table_michael_pc_inflowsql_inFlow_SO_SalesOrder_Line[SalesOrderId2]=SalesOrderId, ROW(Table_michael_pc_inflowsql_inFlow_SO_SalesOrder_Line[SalesOrderId])-1)), ROWS(A$28:A28)), 13),"")
```

After rereading your question, I find it may be possible that I may have flipped the column names and criteria about. If you are actually looking for something closer to For *table*[SalesOrderId]=SalesOrderId **OR** *table*[SalesOrderId]=SalesOrderId2,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table_michael_pc_inflowsql_inFlow_SO_SalesOrder_Line, SMALL(IF(Table_michael_pc_inflowsql_inFlow_SO_SalesOrder_Line[SalesOrderId]=SalesOrderId, ROW(Table_michael_pc_inflowsql_inFlow_SO_SalesOrder_Line[SalesOrderId])-1, IF(Table_michael_pc_inflowsql_inFlow_SO_SalesOrder_Line[SalesOrderId]=SalesOrderId2, ROW(Table_michael_pc_inflowsql_inFlow_SO_SalesOrder_Line[SalesOrderId])-1)), ROWS(A$28:A28)), 13),"")
```

As I'm sure you are aware, array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>.

BTW, you can rename your table with the context menu command Table Tools ► Design ► Properties ► Table Name so that sample formulas are less confusing.

Comment: I tried **AND** or **OR** already, unfortunately doesn't work. It is not the range that changes, its only the criteria which is different.

Comment: you are my hero of the day. That's exactly what I was looking for. I tried the multiple if's but probably placed it wrong. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have one more obstacle to take with this formula. Somtimes I have data in criteria _SalesOrderId2_ and sometimes it's blank. Right now the formula doesn't show any results if _SalesOrderId2_ is blank. How can I make this formula work with one or two criterias?

Comment: @Michael.M - I'm a little unclear on what you want returned if a blank is encountered. Of course, you could double things up in an IF but you want to avoid calculating twice. There might be a way to throw an error into a second part of the formula. Could you edit your original question (or start a new one) to further describe the situation and the expected results?

Comment: I started a new question. index-small-if with one or multiple criterias from the same column